# How to move the body content of pdf report according to header height

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

I am having two plugins where one plugin is used for designing the headers and footers for the reports and another is for writing the body content of the pdf reports.
When the height of the header increases or decreases the body content of the pdf report should move dynamically up and down according to the height of the header. Any solution on this would be very much helpful.

```
def custom_report_pdf
  begin
report = CustomReport.find(params[:id].to_i)
paper_margin = report.paper_margin
paper_orientation = report.paper_orientation 
paper_size = report.paper_size
unless paper_size.nil?
  @page_height = paper_size[:page_height]
  @page_width = paper_size[:page_width]
end
@student_ids = []
query = []
@sorted_description =[]
params[:custom_reports].each do |key,value|
  @student_ids << key if value.to_i == 1
end
@student_ids = CustomReport.sort_by_first_name(@student_ids)
@student_ids.each do |student_id|
    # the content of tinymce description part whole thing is splitted then it is made loop one by one as word
    description = report.description.split
    description.each_with_index do |word, i|
      @value = CustomReport.match_string(query, word, student_id, i, params[:id]).to_s
    end
    @sorted_description << @value
    query = []
  end
  #      if defined? HeaderFooterDesign == 'constant' and HeaderFooterDesign.first.config_key == true
  #        render :pdf => "#{report.name}"
  #      else
  render :pdf => "#{report.name}",
    :orientation => paper_orientation.nil? ? 'Portrait' : paper_orientation,
    :page_height => @page_height.nil? ? '27.94cm' : @page_height+"cm",
    :page_width => @page_width.nil? ? '21.59cm' : @page_width+"cm",
    :margin => paper_margin.nil? ? {:top => '3.2cm',:bottom => '2cm', :left => '2cm',:right => '2.1cm'} : {:top => (paper_margin[:top].to_f+ 3.5).to_s + "cm",:bottom => (paper_margin[:bottom].to_f + 0.2).to_s + "cm", :left => paper_margin[:left]+"cm",:right => (paper_margin[:right].to_f).to_s + "cm" }
  #      end
rescue Exception => e
  Rails.logger.info "Exception in design_custom_reports controller, custom_report_pdf action"
  Rails.logger.info e
  flash[:notice] = "Sorry, something went wrong. Please inform administration"
  redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

end

Comment: Is this the seperate module you have defined, which you are calling somewhere, with the help of defined method 'custom_pdf_report'

Comment: this is the code part of the pdf view. the header of pdf will be coming from different plugin.

Comment: you can try using `bounding_box` by specifying `bounding_box [bounds.left, bounds.top - 105], :width => bounds.width , :height => bounds.height do` something like this, and try calling your headers in this. So according to your `header` height this box size will increase and decrease

Comment: could you please explain this in some detail as to how this could be used.

Answer (score 0):

See below example, how to use `bounding_box`

```
pdf_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{pdf_file_name}.pdf"
Prawn::Document.generate(pdf_file_path, :top_margin => 0, :bottom_margin => 0) do
  font "Helvetica"
  repeat :all do
    # header
    bounding_box [bounds.left, bounds.top], :width => bounds.width, :height => 100 do
      move_down(5)
      text_box "103, 1st Floor, Bldg #42, Jasminium,", :align => :right, :size => 8, :at => [bounds.left, bounds.top - 10]
      text_box "link road extension,", :align => :right, :size => 8, :at => [bounds.left, bounds.top - 20]
      text_box "Bhujbal complex,", :align => :right, :size => 8, :at => [bounds.left, bounds.top - 30]
      text_box "pune", :align => :right, :size => 8, :at => [bounds.left, bounds.top - 40]
      image "#{Rails.root}/public/images/logo.png", :position => :left, :scale => 0.2
      stroke_horizontal_rule
    end

    # footer
    bounding_box [bounds.left, bounds.bottom + 65], :width  => bounds.width, :height => 80 do
      stroke_horizontal_rule
      move_down(5)
      image "#{Rails.root}/public/images/stamp.jpg", :at => [bounds.left, bounds.top - 2], :scale => 0.7
      text "www.google.com", :align => :center
    end
  end
    summary_cells = [[make_cell(:content => "", :background_color => "6E6E6E", :text_color => "FFFFFF"),
      make_cell(:content => "Overview", :background_color => "6E6E6E", :text_color => "FFFFFF"),
      make_cell(:content => "Status", :background_color => "6E6E6E", :text_color => "FFFFFF"),
      make_cell(:content => "Flag", :background_color => "6E6E6E", :text_color => "FFFFFF"),
      make_cell(:content => "Approval Type", :background_color => "6E6E6E", :text_color => "FFFFFF")]]
    @students.each do |b|
      color = case b.status
      when "Active" then "3BA936"
      when "InActive" then "C80000"
      when "InProgress" then "FA9632"
      else "6E6E6E"
      end
      students << b.documents.not_auto.visible
      summary_cells << [b.class.to_s, b.overview, b.completion_status, make_cell(b.status.titleize, :text_color => color), b.linked_task.try(:means_of_approval)]
    end
end
```